# How to change default chocolatey install directory using cmd only?

Tags: cmd, chocolatey

I've installed Chocolatey in `D:\Chocolatey` directory by following steps

https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/wiki/Installation#installing-to-a-different-location

It works, but i have to change environment variable `ChocolateyInstall` and create the folder `D:\Chocolatey` **manually**.

Is there any way do installed Chocolatey in a non-default directory just using cmd?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Set an environment variable from command line

- cmd.exe: `setx ChocolateyInstall D:\Chocolatey /M`
- powershell.exe: `& setx.exe ChocolateyInstall D:\Chocolatey /M`

### For Chocolatey

- cmd.exe: `setx ChocolateyInstall D:\Chocolatey /M && SET "ChocolateyInstall=D:\Chocolatey" && "%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))" && SET "PATH=%PATH%;%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\chocolatey\bin"`

You could simply try just `SET "ChocolateyInstall=D:\Chocolatey"` and see if that works for the installation.

Comment: Hi, I try to set `ChocolateyInstall` before i install chocolatey, but i have to close cmd and re-open it to make chocolatey installed in `D:\chocolatey` (if i don't close cmd and re-open, chocolatey is still installed in default directory `C:\ProgramData\chocolatey`). Do you know any command to close and open a new cmd ?

Comment: Choco comes with `refreshenv`, which will refresh the environment variables without closing cmd - but you need to have choco installed first.

Comment: I added some additional notes to the answer.

Comment: It's really helpful, thank you. I found out that when i use only `setx ChocolateyInstall D:\Chocolatey` i have to close and re-open cmd, but when i use `setx ChocolateyInstall D:\Chocolatey /M && SET "ChocolateyInstall=D:\Chocolatey"` i don't need to do that.